# Failed to show the result

Tags: php, mysql, server

For my project i am using PHP and MySql. In that i was tried to upload an image to the mysql database. In that i faced one terrible error. My html code was like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Learing new things</title>
<style>
body
{
margin:4%;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method=post name=imaging action="upload.php">
<input type="file" name=file><input type="submit" name=upload value=Upload>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

"file" was the name of my file upload field. PHP code like this

```
 <?php

$file=$_FILES['file'];
var_dump($file);
if(isset($_FILES['file']['name']))
{
echo "Image Uploaded";
echo $file['name'];
}
else 
echo "Image not Uploaded";
?>
```

Whatever happen whether the file is uploaded or not uploaded, in my PHP page it is always executing the echo "image upload". i tried without selecting a file and clicked the upload still i am getting the same. How do i find whether a file is selected and uploaded in the html page. why i am getting the same message. it is not executing the else block.

Comment: You are missing a lot of quotes in your html code. you would like to ensure that it gets rendered by most browsers.

Comment: ok thanks for that please answer my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Format html code**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Learing new things</title>
<style>
body
{
margin:4%;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="imaging" action="upload.php">
<input type="file" name="file" /><input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" />
</form>"
</body>
</html>
```

**Php check if file was selected**

```
if (empty($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
    // No file was selected for upload
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your Php script to this.

```
<?php
$target_dir = "(your target directory)/";
$target_file = $target_dir .basename($_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["upload"])) {
$check = getimagesize($_FILES["uploadfile"]["tmp_name"]);
if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
} else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
}
?>
```